# Hoe to set route into dispatch.yaml

Tags: google-app-engine

I have three different services in an App Engine.
I have 3 different routes, each of which should be routed to different services.

api.carspecialsxxx.com
Target => default (Welcome page)

api.carspecialsxxx.com/api/v1/...
Target => apiv1 (API V1)

api.carspecialsxxx.com/api/v2/...
Target => apiv2 (API V2)

How do I realize this in the dispatch.yaml

```
dispatch:
     - url: "api.carspecialsxxx.com/*"
       service: default
     - url: "api.carspecialsxxx.com/api/v1/*"
       service: apiv1
     - url: "api.carspecialsxxx.com/api/v2/*"
       service: apiv2
```

Comment: Your domain is validated on your project? when you have ready your file dispatch yaml is necessary to run this command 

    #gcloud app deploy dispatch.yaml

in order to refresh your routes in app engine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of the dispatch rules matters, the first pattern match wins.

The pattern you have for the `default` service actually matches the requests for the other 2 services as well, so it wins - all requests are being sent to the `default` service, none makes it to the other services.

You need to put the least specific patterns (the rule for the `default` service in your case) *after* the more specific ones. In your case that would mean placing it last.

But since the target of that last rule would be the `default` service you can completely leave it out - requests which don't match any rule patterns in `dispatch.yaml` file (evaluated in their order in the file) will be sent to the `default` service anyways.